# Problem in listening to multicast in multihomed Linux server

Tags: linux, multicast

I am trying to write a multicast client on a machine with two NICs, and I can't make it work. I can see with a sniffer that once I start the program the NIC (eth4) start receiving the multicast datagrams:
y.y.y.y. (some ip) -> z.z.z.z (multicast ip, not my eth4 NIC IP) UDP Source port: kkk (some other port) Destination port: xxx (multicast port)

However, I can't get those packets using my program (listening to port xxx on eth4).

I also added:
route add 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth4

Searched the web for some examples/explanations, but it seems like I do what everybody else does. Any help will be appreciated. 
is there anything else to do with route/iptables?

Comment: Question related to this was already moved to stack overflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132654/problem-in-listening-to-multicast-in-c-with-multiple-nics

Comment: yeh, I want to make sure my Linux configuration is fine. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to debug this is to run `tcpdump` on correct interface. If you can receive packets using `tcpdump`, then your setup is working fine, and problem is with your code.

Programming related questions should go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (also wait for answers to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132654/problem-in-listening-to-multicast-in-c-with-multiple-nics)).

Comment: as I said, tcpdump shows the packets received by multicast IP, not my eth4 NIC static IP. is that how should I see it? shouldn't tcpdump show the packets arriving to my NIC static ip?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that from your question. Yes, that's how it should work. You receive multicast packets to multicast IP, not to your own IP address.